# Babel not compiling vendors chuck

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I migrated to Webpack 4 and set up everything according to the Docs, however, my `vendors.js` chunk is not getting compiled like the main.js chunk.

I have placed the `vendors` into the `optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups` object, as the docs suggested, but didnt find a way to make these `"cacheGroups"` get compiled with babel.

My problem is that one of the libraries has a ES6 `class` and now IE11 isnt working due to this fact.

My webpack `optimization` object looks like:

```
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        styles: {
          name: 'styles',
          test: /\.css$/,
          chunks: 'all',
          enforce: true
        },
        vendor: {
          name: 'vendor',
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          chunks: 'all',
          enforce: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Is there a way to force webpack to compile vendors with babel as well?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should have posted the entire `webpack` config to give people more context.

Anyways, `optimization` step has very little to do with the actual transpiling. Your `vendor` chunk is set to only include stuff from `node_modules` which is almost never processed (unless you specifically tell `babel-loader` to include a certain package).

Since I do not know how you configured your `babel-loader` I would suggest something along these lines:

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: (file) => {
        return /node_modules/.test(file) && !file.includes("/node_modules/my-es6-module/");
    }
}
```

The idea is to exclude all files containing `node_modules` unless the file path contains the name of your specific module which you do need to process with babel.

In general, having an ES6 code published to `npm` is a very bad practice and should be avoided at all costs.

If this is not enough, please do update your question with your webpack config to give us more insight into your setup.